# Real analysis question about stein book

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I think (c) is not true for some measurable functions as f=1 and g=1 for all x $\in$ $R^d$. Should I understand f, g as integrable? or is there any other options?

Comment: Yes, you have to suppose $f$ and $g$ integrable.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response! Thank you